# Support of a probability distribution

Tags: probability, distributions

Consider a bivariate probability distribution $G$ and a random vector $(X_1,X_2)$. Should $G$   satisfy any specific **support** restrictions in order to be an admissible probability distribution for each of these 3 vectors contemporaneously
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
X_1\\
X_2
\end{pmatrix}\quad\begin{pmatrix}
X_1-X_2\\
-X_2
\end{pmatrix}\quad \begin{pmatrix}
-X_1\\
X_2-X_1
\end{pmatrix}\quad
$$
I understand that $G$ should satisfy some **shape** restrictions in order to be an admissible distribution of the 3 vectors above. For example, the first marginal of $G$ should be symmetric around zero. Here, however, I'm wondering about support restrictions. For instance, should  $G$ have support "degenerate" in some dimension? Or should $G$ have full support?

Comment: Do you want to place some restrictions on $X_1$ and $X_2$?  Because if $X_1=X_2$, the three vectors have _different_ degenerate bivariate distributions  and so a single bivariate distribution cannot possibly be an admissible distribution for all three of the vectors.

Comment: No, I don't want to impose such restrictions on $X_1, X_2$

Comment: The conditions immediately imply the $X_i$ are symmetric around $0$ and that their sum has the same support as either one.  The latter (trivially) implies this common support must be closed under addition (and therefore under subtraction), thereby making it an additive subgroup of the real numbers.  Such a support is often termed a "lattice."

Comment: Thanks. (1) "their sum has the same support as either one": do I interpret correctly as saying $\text{Supp}(X_1+X_2)=\text{Supp}(X_1)$ and/or $\text{Supp}(X_1+X_2)=\text{Supp}(X_2)$. (2) "The latter (trivially) implies this common support must be closed under addition (and therefore under subtraction), thereby making it an additive subgroup of the real numbers". Could you make an example of a support that violates this?

Comment: (3) Suppose for example that $G\sim \mathcal{N}\Big(\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1\\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\Big)$. Observe that $G$ is an admissible distribution for the three vectors. In fact, we can take $(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)\sim \mathcal{N}\Big(\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1& 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\Big)$. Then, we can define $X_1\equiv (Y_1-Y_3)$ and $X_2\equiv (Y_2-Y_3)$. It follows that $(X_1,X_2), (X_1-X_2, -X_2), (-X_1, X_2-X_1)$ have distribution $G$. Does such $G$ satisfy the restrictions you suggest?

Comment: You ask for an example of a set of real numbers that is the support of a random variable but is not additively closed.  The support of a Bernoulli variable is $\{0,1\}.$ It is not closed under addition because $1+1=2 \notin \{0,1\}.$  Concerning your comment (3), since the support of any nondegenerate Normal variable is the entire set of real numbers, it is perforce additively closed. When the variable is also symmetric around $0,$ if it is degenerate its support is $0,$ which obviously is additively closed, too.